# Can't seem to get tagsinput-typeahead to work with a remote MySQL source

Tags: jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6, JQuery 1.11.0, Bootstrap3-typeahead 4.0.2, and bootstrap-tagsinput 0.8.0.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {  
        $('.tagsinput-typeahead').tagsinput({
          confirmKeys: [13],
          itemValue: 'value',
          itemText: 'text',   
          typeahead: {
                displayKey: 'text',
                afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
                source: function (query) {
                    return jQuery.get("typeaheadSource.php?q=" + query);
                 // return jQuery.post("typeaheadSource.php?q=" + query); //  I tried both get and post
                  }
            }
    });
}); 

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Job Number(s) </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control tagsinput-typeahead" name="typeahead" id="typeahead" ></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my typeaheadSource.php:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {    
    $query = $_REQUEST['q'];
    $sql = "SELECT jobno, jobname FROM jobs WHERE jobno LIKE '%" . $query . "%' ORDER BY jobno DESC LIMIT 20";
    $result=db_query($sql);
    while($row = db_nextrow($result)) {
        $array[] = array('value' => $row['jobno'], 'text' => $row['jobname']);
    }
    if (isset($array)) {
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

The output if I run typeaheadSource.php directly looks like this:

```
[{"value":"2012006.00","text":"Monterey Hotel Investigation"},{"value":"2006142.00","text":"Ollendorff Residence"},{"value":"2006141.01","text":"MLK Student Union Peer Review Expanded Scope"},{"value":"2006141.00","text":"MLK Student Union Peer Review"}]
```

And if I take that output & put it into my code as the source, everything works great.

```
$('.tagsinput-typeahead').tagsinput({
      confirmKeys: [13],
      itemValue: 'value',
      itemText: 'text',
      typeahead: {
            displayKey: 'text',
            afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
            source: [{"value":"2012006.00","text":"Monterey Hotel Investigation"},{"value":"2006142.00","text":"Ollendorff Residence"},{"value":"2006141.01","text":"MLK Student Union Peer Review Expanded Scope"}] 
      }
});
```

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZseI.png)

But when my source calls my remote URL, the typeahead doesn't show up & I don't get any errors.

```
source: function (query) {
  return jQuery.get("typeaheadSource.php?q=" + query);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion or advice on how to get this to work with a remote URL querying a MySQL DB?

Answer (score -1):

use jquery auto complete as following 
1- activete  tagsinput `<input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" />`
to bind jquery auto complete tagsinput generate this class bootstrap-tagsinput.
2- here is the needed code

```
 $(".bootstrap-tagsinput > input").autocomplete({

                      source: function (request, response) {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              url: url,
                              data: data,
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function (data) {
                                  response(data.d);
                              },
                              error: function (result) {

                              }
                          });
                      }
                  });
```

- add all referance files jquery, jquery custom.js for auto complete, auto complete css,